# Karma + Jasmine - Default unit test "it should create" failing with error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an extremely simple unit test -- the test that is automatically generated by Angular.

```
import { Component, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { CtaSecondaryComponent } from './cta-secondary.component';

describe('CtaSecondaryComponent', () => {
  let component: CtaSecondaryComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CtaSecondaryComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CtaSecondaryComponent ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CtaSecondaryComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

I am getting an error about 50% of the time (i.e. no changes to the test -- sometimes it fails sometimes it passes):

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined thrown
```

As far as I can tell, there is no reference to nativeElement anywhere in this component. In fact, there is no reference to nativeElement anywhere in this entire project. I cannot find anyone else with this issue online. Can anyone provide some input?

### cta-secondary.component.html

```
<!-- button -->
<button [ngClass]="{'disabled': disabled}" class="btn btn-secondary">
  <span>{{label}}</span>
</button>
```

### cta-secondary.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, HostListener, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'fuse-cta-secondary',
  templateUrl: './cta-secondary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cta-secondary.component.scss']
})
export class CtaSecondaryComponent implements OnInit {
  // label for cta secondary
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() disabled: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Versions:

angular/core: 8.2.2

karma: 6.3.4

jasmine-core: 2.99.1

node: 12.18.3

Comment: UPDATE: Switching from chrome-headless as the browser to PhantomJS appears to have solved the issue. Perhaps chrome-headless had cached something. Either way, this appears to be working as expected now.

Comment: I was going to tell you to try removing `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` because I don't think you need it to see if it would fix the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I had left that in there from a previous attempt to resolve this. As you pointed out -- it made no difference in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up "solving" this myself. Switching to PhantomJS from chrome-headless as the browser in karma.config.js to appears to have solved the issue. Perhaps chrome-headless had cached something. Either way, this appears to be working as expected now.

Maybe someone else can chime in on if there's some sort of cache resetting that needs to be done in headless-chrome?